# Scrapy Item Loaders - start processing from a given node not root Selector

Tags: scrapy

I have an xpath expression which leads to a 'product' element on a page (actually HTML5 microdata). Nested under this element are various other elements for the product name, description, price etc.

Currently I'm passing in the root selector object to the Item Loader and then constructing a very long xpath statement to retrieve the product attributes e.g.

```
l.add_xpath('name', {LONG XPATH TO PRODUCT ELEMENT} + {LONG XPATH TO NAME ELEMENT})
l.add_xpath('price', {LONG XPATH TO PRODUCT ELEMENT} + {LONG XPATH TO PRICE ELEMENT})
```

This seems pretty inefficient in terms of xpath processing, is there a way to tell the ItemLoader to start from a given node? or do I need to write my own ItemLoader to handle this scenario? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was actually pretty obvious now I understand more about selectors. selector.xpath() returns a list of selectors so I can do something like:

```
productSelector = selector.xpath({xpath to product})[0] # assumes match

l = ItemLoader(item=productItem, selector=productSelector)
l.add_xpath('name', {xpath to product name})
```

Comment: I would also emphasize that the key to the solution is that `selector` argument. of the loader.